# Swift 5 UITableViewCell : Multiple row insertion instead of single row

Tags: swift, uitableview, sections

When I implemented the following code, instead of inserting a single row in the section, two rows are being inserted.

```
    var rowcount = 2 


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return  rowcount

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailAddIngredientID", for: indexPath) as! DetailAddIngredientTableViewCell 
          cell.addMoreButton.tag = indexPath.section
          cell.addMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addMoreField(_:)), for: .allTouchEvents)
          return cell
    }


    @objc func addMoreField(_ sender : UIButton){   
        rowcount = rowcount + 1
        detailTable.beginUpdates()
        detailTable.insertRows(at: [(NSIndexPath(row: rowcount - 1, section: 1) as IndexPath)], with: .automatic)  
        detailTable.endUpdates()
    }
```

How can I insert only a single row in the section?

Comment: The `UIControl.Event`  `.allTouchEvents` is going to mean your function is called multiple times every time the button is tapped.  Does changing it to `.touchUpInside` fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks , it worked @rbaldwin. As you mentioned above, it changed it to `.touchUpInside`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused on this line:

```
cell.addMoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addMoreField(_:)), for: .allTouchEvents)
```

You are using `.allTouchEvents` for the `UIControl.Event` which will cause your function to be called multiple times every time the button is tapped.

Changing that to `.touchUpInside` will fix the issue by only responding once, when the user touches the button and then lifts their finger off.  This is the default event used for buttons.